# TimerTask and Timer: behaviour of instance variable

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle, timertask

In the below code, when I change orientation of the device, I am still getting previous values of variable "count", along with a new counter for "count", what could I derive from this behaviour? **Is the TimerTask holding reference of "count" variable ?**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private int count;
private TimerTask timerTask;
private Timer timer;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    timerTask = new MyTimerTask();
    timer = new Timer(true);
    //running timer task as daemon thread
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 1000);
 }

 class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        count++;
        System.out.println("*** " + count + " ***");
    }
 }
}
```

[image]

Comment: So, do you want to reset timer when device changes orientation?

Comment: Is the TimerTask holding reference of "count" variable ? Otherwise it should start from zero.

Comment: yes, it holds reference to count variable and old timertask is not destroyed which is potential memory leak

Comment: Ok I see, how this is happening, I do not get it (How TimerTask can have a reference of a variable of a separate class ?). Can you please refer me something.

Comment: I added answer and some reference link for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you have memory leak there which is caused by not cancelled previous `Timer` and keeping reference to `count` variable. That's why even when Activity is destroyed, your old timer is still increasing the old count variable, and as activity is being recreated, there'll be new Timer object and new count variable. Therefore, you'll see 2 counters at the same time.

Solution is cancelling the timer when activity is destroyed:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    timer.cancel();
}
```

If you want to read more about memory leaks, you can checkout [this](https://medium.com/@ankit.sinhal/avoid-memory-leaks-reference-afd0e9dbb213) article.

Comment: Could it be timer.cancel() first and super.onDestroy(), second ?

Comment: For me it works, even if I cancel the timer after `super.onDestroy()`. According to many sample code I have seen, it shouldn't be problem if you write your code after  `super.onDestroy()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cancel the timer in `onDestroy` by calling `timerTask.cancel();`.

Answer (score -1):

open your android manifest file and change in Activity tag as following

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```